# How Formatter works with BufferedWriter without closing?

Tags: java, bufferedwriter, formatter

While learning Java I have found (and hastily used in my code) the following code pattern from [JDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Formatter.java#Formatter.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.OutputStream%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.util.Locale%29):

```
public Formatter(OutputStream os, String csn, Locale l)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    this(l, new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, csn)));
}
```

It passes a newly created `BufferedWriter` to the [other constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Formatter.java#Formatter.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Locale%2Cjava.lang.Appendable%29) referring to it as an `Appendable` interface (so that it cannot be further flushed or closed in the `Formatter` implementation):

```
private Formatter(Locale l, Appendable a) {
    this.a = a;
    this.l = l;
    this.zero = getZero(l);
}
```

After some thinking and digging out `BufferedWriter` code, I cannot understand how this can work properly - from the `BufferedWriter` code it looks like it will lose buffered data if not closed when done. The `Finalize` method seems to not be used. There are a bunch of other constructors in the `Formatter` class which use `BufferedWriter` in a similar manner (mostly wrapping output streams and files). So how does the buffer flushing work in this code? Or is this a bunch of bugs in JDK (which sounds for me unbelievable since it is very basic and old functionality)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Formatter is a Closeable. Just like Output streams, it's thus supposed to be closed by the user of the formatter, and closing it closes the backing BufferedWriter (and wrapped OutputStream, transitively):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Formatter.java#Formatter.close%28%29

It's thus the responsibility of the client code to close the Formatter if it was constructed with an OutputStream.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. I was under impression that if we stored the reference only via Appendable interface, then we are unable to call close() on it. Completely forgot about instanceof magic and type-casting possibility.